# NextJS 13: res in change to NextResponse on api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

i have code that work in under next js 13 version but didnt work on next js 13 (the code below is nextjs 13 code)

```
export async function GET(req : NextRequest){

  const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public/cv-ferdinand-felix.pdf');
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=cv-ferdinand-felix.txt',
  };

  fileStream(NextResponse)
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "CV Downloaded", headers }, { status: 200 });

}
```

its work if nextresponse we change to res default but its not supported in next js new version, how can i fix it

i tried to make a feature that once we click an CTA button, we have an api that have a function to download a file in the app.. i am searching for fix it, its work under nextjs 13.. but the nextjs 13 change the res to nextresponse.. so it cant to do,, how can i fix it